# Vectors, when to re-reference elements

Tags: c++, vector, data-structures

So far I have only worked with lists in C++ (Queues, stacks, tree etc.. in Java). I have done some reading and have endeavoured to learn about Vectors as they are good for traversal compared to lists and don't have the complexity of Arrays in regards to house keeping.

So far I am aware that there can be an issue in regards to pointer validation in the event the Vector needs to be reallocated. The pickle being (as far as I know) no real way to determine if the adding of an element to the Vector will trigger reallocation.

One answer I can think of is to re-assign the pointers to each element every time an element is added or removed.

This seems like a decent amount of overhead on the chance reallocation is done. Is there a better way perhaps?

Comment: "The pickle being (as far as I know) no real way to determine if the adding of an element to the Vector will trigger reallocation." - there is. read the documentation of vector, it tells you exactly which operations invalidate pointers and iterators.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't asking what can potentially cause invalid pointers in the event of reallocation. I was asking about methods to deal with the invalid pointers and if there is a better way

Comment: @userXXX You reassign all pointers and iterators after performing an operator that invalidates them. Everything else is UB.

Comment: Thanks, I guess reassigning all pointers and iterators is the way to go. Are you saying you will always know if for example adding an element to the vector will cause reallocation and make the pointers invalid? You say it like you will always know if that will happen.

Comment: @userXXX no, you don't know if reallocation will always happen. and you don't need to know it either. you only know what the documentation says: that pointers and iterators are invalidated. How? Why? Irrelevant.

Comment: So someone just went through all my posts and down-voted them. I really hope you wouldn't go that low Croissant, if you did you should be ashamed.

Comment: @userXXX No, I didn't do that. I did, however, downvote this particular question of yours, but not others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to approach this is just to have a vector *of* pointers (preferably smart pointers, so you don't need to worry about manual deallocation).

E.g. instead of

```
std::vector<MyObject> vec;
vec.push_back(MyObject());
MyObject* ptr = &vec[0];
```

Do something like this:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyObject>>
vec.push_back(std::unique_ptr<MyObject>(new MyObject()));  // *
MyObject* ptr = vec[0].get();
```

(* or use `vec.push_back(std::make_unique<MyObject>())` in C++14)

If done in the second way, `ptr` will always be valid across internal reallocations of the vector, because it's not pointing to memory that is managed by the vector, it is pointing to memory that is managed by the unique_ptr, which will not change until the object is explicitly released or destroyed.

Comment: and superfluously wasteful too.

Comment: You seem like one grumpy croissant. At least he gave an answer in line with what I was asking.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Wasteful of what, exactly? Memory? Processor time (on account of multiple indirection)? Yes, *potentially* it could be wasteful of either of these things, but without knowing the questioner's use case and taking a profile of his or her program, you have no idea whether it matters or not. First write in a way that's easy to write and easy to maintain, then worry about performance after you can prove that it is worth worrying about.

Comment: @TylerMcHenry Having an array of objects is easy to write and easy to maintain. It's not a coincidence the idiomatic way of storing objects in std containers is to store them directly. C++ has clear value semantics.

Comment: And the questioner clearly has an need that is not well-addressed by value semantics. Manually responding to every possible invalidation scenario seems considerably more cumbersome than using smart pointers in a vector.